# Execution failed for task ':ai_barcode:compileDebugKotlin'. A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

```
e: /Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ai_barcode-2.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/air/ai_barcode/AndroidCreatorViewFactory.kt: (15, 1): Class 'AndroidCreatorViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ai_barcode-2.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/air/ai_barcode/AndroidCreatorViewFactory.kt: (17, 5): 'create' overrides nothing
e: /Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ai_barcode-2.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/air/ai_barcode/AndroidScannerViewFactory.kt: (14, 1): Class 'AndroidScannerViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ai_barcode-2.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/air/ai_barcode/AndroidScannerViewFactory.kt: (16, 5): 'create' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ai_barcode:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

'''

Comment: flutter clean - flutter pub get didn't solve my problem

Comment: post full error log using ====>    flutter run -- verbose

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Go to your **build.gradle** file in the root of your **Android** directory

[image]

**Step 2**

****Upgrade your Kotlin_version to****

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Rebuild your project by following the Commands

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get
>
> flutter run